# how to get a list of all the boolean fields of a node?

Tags: 8

I need to get a list of all the boolean fields of the node

My code

```
 $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
   ->condition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
   ->condition('type', 'product')
```

Please help me

Comment: Do you know the name of the boolean fields

Comment: Get the base and bundle field definitions from the node class and loop through them to check what type those fields are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a list of an entity's field definitions with [EntityFieldManager::getFieldDefinitions()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFieldManager.php/function/EntityFieldManager%3A%3AgetFieldDefinitions/8.5.x). You should then have a list of fields defined on that entity and should be able to determine which are the boolean fields.

You can access this via a service like:

```
$product_field_definitions = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('node', 'product');
```